# Change word "Chapter" in "Heading 1" to "Section" using MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a large MS Word document and I would like to have "chapter" numbers appear along with the page number at the foot of the page. I inserted a "Header 1" style and (almost) everything worked - the page numbers look like I want them to. In the document, the line with the "Header 1" style says "Chapter 1."

At this point, everything is functionally fine. The only thing I want to do is change the word "Chapter" to "Section" - nothing else. However, that appears to be impossible.

I have searched the document for the word "Chapter" but it does not appear when I do a search. I have made all text visible, but still nothing. I have expanded field codes and still, I cannot find the word "Chapter" to change it to "Section." I am using an older version of MS Word (2013) so this may have been changed in a later release. If that is the case, I would like to know so I can quit banging my head against the wall.

I know this is merely an aesthetic change, but it would improve the look of the document.

Comment: Where did you "insert" a "header 1" style? And do you mean Heading 1? Is the document based on a freely available template, an in-house thing or something commercial?

Comment: Did my answer address your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the "Chapter" comes in the numbering. This is best done following Shauna Kelly's instructions in [her page on Automatic Numbering](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html).

### After following those instructions, you would use the Define New MultiLevel List dialog and insert the word "Section" instead of "Chapter."

[image: screenshot of dialog]

It would help if you could attach a [view link to a sample document](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258).